# my UIScrollView is not working

Tags: uiscrollview

This is what i have so far. What I am trying to do is have a top scroll bar with buttons on it that take you to different pages. I am adding this UIScrollView here and the button, but i cannot get it to show up on the screen. I want the top scroll to be 500 pixels (to fit other buttons) and i want the button i have there to be in the middle of the screen on startup. I think my probl has to do with the coordinates that i have put in, but i have been changing them around for a few hours now and i still cant get it.

```
    // init top Scroller
UIScrollView *topScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-90,0, 60, 500)];
topScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(60,500);
topScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:topScroll];
[topScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

//add current games button
UIButton *currentGamesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
currentGamesButton.frame = CGRectMake (227, 0,55,55);
[currentGamesButton addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(goToCurrentGamesViewController:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[currentGamesButton setTitle:@"Current Games" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[topScroll addSubview:currentGamesButton];
```

Comment: If your scroll view is 60px wide and located -90px to the left of your view, I would guess that's why you're not seeing it.

Comment: aha... that got the button to show up =) thanks... i mixed up width and height...thanks

Comment: it scrolls up and down... how do i change that so that it scrolls side to side?

Comment: you need to define your contentSize property accordingly... (width, height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question: as stated by SuperRod on March 30th is that the location of my button was out of the screen. Sorry for the noobish question, and i plan on double checking my code before i put it on the website.